# Installing tensorflow on Google Colaboratory shows a dependency problem

Tags: pip, google-colaboratory

```
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/ae/0b08f53498417914f2274cc3b5576d2b83179b0cbb209457d0fde0152174/tensorflow-2.3.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (320.4MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 320.4MB 49kB/s 
Collecting protobuf>=3.9.2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/14/dc43f81adc543c435cfeb45dd4ac048a97a1eb621c2ccb68ab3d15118737/protobuf-3.12.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.3MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 54.5MB/s 
Collecting google-pasta>=0.1.8
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/de/c648ef6835192e6e2cc03f40b19eeda4382c49b5bafb43d88b931c4c74ac/google_pasta-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (57kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 10.2MB/s 
Collecting absl-py>=0.7.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/53/9243c600e047bd4c3df9e69cfabc1e8004a82cac2e0c484580a78a94ba2a/absl-py-0.9.0.tar.gz (104kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 61.6MB/s 
Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/48/a76be51647d0eb9f10e2a4511bf3ffb8cc1e6b14e9e4fab46173aa79f981/termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting scipy==1.4.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/29/162476fd44203116e7980cfbd9352eef9db37c49445d1fec35509022f6aa/scipy-1.4.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.1MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 26.1MB 116kB/s 
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/61/91641ea993600493d37f4897dc14ef396086868c586869937f6d57479a13/grpcio-1.31.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.4MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.4MB 48.2MB/s 
Collecting h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/06/cafdd44889200e5438b897388f3075b52a8ef01f28a17366d91de0fa2d05/h5py-2.10.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.9MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.9MB 50.8MB/s 
Collecting tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/1b/6a420d7e6ba431cf3d51b2a5bfa06a958c4141e3189385963dc7f6fbffb6/tensorboard-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.8MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 6.8MB 48.8MB/s 
Collecting wrapt>=1.11.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/f7/e43cefbe88c5fd371f4cf0cf5eb3feccd07515af9fd6cf7dbf1d1793a797/wrapt-1.12.1.tar.gz
Collecting opt-einsum>=2.3.2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/19/404708a7e54ad2798907210462fd950c3442ea51acc8790f3da48d2bee8b/opt_einsum-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (65kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 11.1MB/s 
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<2.4.0,>=2.3.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/ed/5853ec0ae380cba4588eab1524e18ece1583b65f7ae0e97321f5ff9dfd60/tensorflow_estimator-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (459kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 460kB 53.6MB/s 
Collecting astunparse==1.6.3
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/03/13dde6512ad7b4557eb792fbcf0c653af6076b81e5941d36ec61f7ce6028/astunparse-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel>=0.26
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/23/848298cccf8e40f5bbb59009b32848a4c38f4e7f3364297ab3c3e2e2cd14/wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting gast==0.3.3
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/84/759f5dd23fec8ba71952d97bcc7e2c9d7d63bdc582421f3cd4be845f0c98/gast-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.12.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/ff/48bde5c0f013094d729fe4b0316ba2a24774b3ff1c52d924a8a4cb04078a/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting keras-preprocessing<1.2,>=1.1.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/4c/7c3275a01e12ef9368a892926ab932b33bb13d55794881e3573482b378a7/Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 8.6MB/s 
Collecting numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b3/a9/b1bc4c935ed063766bce7d3e8c7b20bd52e515ff1c732b02caacf7918e5a/numpy-1.18.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (20.1MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 20.1MB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ed/16/e9f5c5b86696da09298ea10c32d68ad8ea21f888e45b11aa9e615adda6c9/setuptools-49.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (789kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 798kB 52.8MB/s 
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.15
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/94/5f7079a0e00bd6863ef8f1da638721e9da21e5bacee597595b318f71d62e/Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 307kB 52.4MB/s 
Collecting google-auth<2,>=1.6.3
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/79/4c59796bb02535aee5e5d2e2c5e16008aaf48903c2ec2ff566a2774bb3e0/google_auth-1.20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 13.4MB/s 
Collecting tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/85/5c5ac0a8c5efdfab916e9c6bc18963f6a6996a8a1e19ec4ad8c9ac9c623c/tensorboard_plugin_wit-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (779kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 788kB 54.0MB/s 
Collecting requests<3,>=2.21.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/1e/0c169c6a5381e241ba7404532c16a21d86ab872c9bed8bdcd4c423954103/requests-2.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/63/eaec2bd025ab48c754b55e8819af0f6a69e2b1e187611dd40cbbe101ee7f/Markdown-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (88kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 13.4MB/s 
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/b8/88def36e74bee9fce511c9519571f4e485e890093ab7442284f4ffaef60b/google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/de/214830a981892a3e286c3794f41ae67a4495df1108c3da8a9f62159b9a9d/pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 54.5MB/s 
Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.5"
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/df/c3587a667d6b308fadc90b99e8bc8774788d033efcc70f4ecaae7fad144b/rsa-4.6-py3-none-any.whl (47kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 8.3MB/s 
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/5c/f3aa86b6d5482f3051b433c7616668a9b96fbe49a622210e2c9781938a5c/cachetools-4.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/38/928ddce2273eaa564f6f50de919327bf3a00f091b5baba8dfa9460f3a8a8/idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/c4/6c4fe722df5343c33226f0b4e0bb042e4dc13483228b4718baf286f86d87/certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/f0/a391d1463ebb1b233795cabfc0ef38d3db4442339de68f847026199e69d7/urllib3-1.25.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/58/cdea07eb51fc2b906db0968a94700866fc46249bdc75cac23f9d13168929/importlib_metadata-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/12/b92740d845ab62ea4edf04d2f4164d82532b5a0b03836d4d4e71c6f3d379/requests_oauthlib-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/1e/a94a8d635fa3ce4cfc7f506003548d0a2447ae76fd5ca53932970fe3053f/pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 12.2MB/s 
Collecting zipp>=0.5
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/34/bfcb43cc0ba81f527bc4f40ef41ba2ff4080e047acb0586b56b3d017ace4/zipp-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting oauthlib>=3.0.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/57/ce2e7a8fa7c0afb54a0581b14a65b56e62b5759dbc98e80627142b8a3704/oauthlib-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: absl-py, termcolor, wrapt
  Building wheel for absl-py (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for absl-py: filename=absl_py-0.9.0-cp36-none-any.whl size=121931 sha256=85a9d87c8ec866ac12d5b25049a090ab949857c4d39d4793b368cff06c7e94ac
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/8e/28/49/fad4e7f0b9a1227708cbbee4487ac8558a7334849cb81c813d
  Building wheel for termcolor (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for termcolor: filename=termcolor-1.1.0-cp36-none-any.whl size=4832 sha256=2c15675c61e919a4f30b0b4c575b43abf65cf7b7e671c24e2df484b0fcf669ff
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/7c/06/54/bc84598ba1daf8f970247f550b175aaaee85f68b4b0c5ab2c6
  Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for wrapt: filename=wrapt-1.12.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl size=67489 sha256=75a9a273381441c10d1d2bbe7305c9bb68ce54033a916bea154a55afc4a208c1
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/b1/c2/ed/d62208260edbd3fa7156545c00ef966f45f2063d0a84f8208a
Successfully built absl-py termcolor wrapt
ERROR: kaggle 1.5.6 has requirement urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1, but you'll have urllib3 1.25.10 which is incompatible.
ERROR: google-colab 1.0.0 has requirement google-auth~=1.17.2, but you'll have google-auth 1.20.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: google-colab 1.0.0 has requirement requests~=2.23.0, but you'll have requests 2.24.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: datascience 0.10.6 has requirement folium==0.2.1, but you'll have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: albumentations 0.1.12 has requirement imgaug<0.2.7,>=0.2.5, but you'll have imgaug 0.2.9 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: six, setuptools, protobuf, google-pasta, absl-py, termcolor, numpy, scipy, grpcio, h5py, werkzeug, wheel, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, rsa, cachetools, google-auth, tensorboard-plugin-wit, idna, chardet, certifi, urllib3, requests, zipp, importlib-metadata, markdown, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, google-auth-oauthlib, tensorboard, wrapt, opt-einsum, tensorflow-estimator, astunparse, gast, keras-preprocessing, tensorflow
Successfully installed absl-py-0.9.0 astunparse-1.6.3 cachetools-4.1.1 certifi-2020.6.20 chardet-3.0.4 gast-0.3.3 google-auth-1.20.1 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.1 google-pasta-0.2.0 grpcio-1.31.0 h5py-2.10.0 idna-2.10 importlib-metadata-1.7.0 keras-preprocessing-1.1.2 markdown-3.2.2 numpy-1.18.5 oauthlib-3.1.0 opt-einsum-3.3.0 protobuf-3.12.4 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 requests-2.24.0 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 rsa-4.6 scipy-1.4.1 setuptools-49.2.1 six-1.15.0 tensorboard-2.3.0 tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.7.0 tensorflow-2.3.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.3.0 termcolor-1.1.0 urllib3-1.25.10 werkzeug-1.0.1 wheel-0.34.2 wrapt-1.12.1 zipp-3.1.0
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 550, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-target-x6fc9bjj/lib/python/protobuf-3.12.4-py3.6-nspkg.pth' -> '/content/notebooks/protobuf-3.12.4-py3.6-nspkg.pth'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 505, in run
    options.target_dir, target_temp_dir, options.upgrade
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 563, in _handle_target_dir
    target_item_dir
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 564, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 263, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/notebooks/protobuf-3.12.4-py3.6-nspkg.pth'
WARNING: The following packages were previously imported in this runtime:
  [cachetools,certifi,chardet,google,idna,numpy,oauthlib,pyasn1,pyasn1_modules,requests_oauthlib,rsa,six]
You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions.
```

As you can see, kaggle, google-colab, datascience and albumentations show dependency problem. When I tried installing them manually, they show another dependency problem and I become so puzzled that I don't know what to do. I think it may be related to Colab because when I try installing tensorflow in my computer, it works well. How can I solve this dependency problem?

Comment: Doesn't google colab already has all dependencies pre-installed?

Comment: @Eduardo Savrin Savrin I've started google colab very recently so I have no idea

Comment: It has all libraries already installed . Just write code and run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Colab usually have all the libraries pre-installled in it. Most of the time you will not need to install any library. In case you find that something is missing then you can install them easily using:

`!pip install tensorflow==1.2`

If you want to install system libs then :

`!apt-get -qq install -y libfluidsynth1`

see the syntax is similar to Jupyter Notebook